# using EF4.1, is it possible to add constraints on CF generated Database during Seed()?

Tags: entity-framework

While eagerly awaiting direct support for UNIQUE constraints in EF's CodeFirst (going against SQL2k8R2), I am currently running a SQL Script that does the ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT after CF creates the DB for me.

I would like to somehow programmatically add these UNIQUE constraints right after CF creates the schema, maybe via ALTER TABLE?

Im thinking of maybe doing it in the Seed() override somehow?

Possible?

Comment: UNIQUE constraint support was removed from the next EF release so you will be waiting next few years (at least to .NET 4.5 SP1 or .NET 5).

Comment: Bummer!  Thats too bad - I was (somewhat patiently) waiting for Enums and UNIQUE constraint support in the next release after 4.2.  Could I ask where you read this?  I checked on the the ADO.NET blog and didnt find anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a [Database Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) to create constraints.

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //your logic here
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT con_first UNIQUE (first_name);");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that easy huh :-)  Sorry for the stupid question, and thank you for the answer.  I didnt know I could do stuff directly to the DB behind EFs back.

Comment: This solution worked for me but with a slight alteration (I'm using SQL Server). I had to add brackets to the table and column names like so: `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [customer] ADD CONSTRAINT con_first UNIQUE ([first_name]);"); ` Hope this is of some help to future visitors.